# Removing and adding search filters with Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a search field that uses a Drop down list to Filter search results by division.

I finally got it working great but now I want to make an ALL option to negate this. The drop down values are equal to an int.   I am still learning so the only way I can bend my mind around this would be a if else statement in the where query.  When i did that i saw a lot of red.

There are 5 options on the Drop down list. The values are 1 through 5. 5 = all.  I want to basically stop searching by division or eliminate the `t0.DivisionID == DDLInt &&`

```
string DDL = DDLAddDivision.SelectedValue;
int DDLInt;
if (int.TryParse(DDL, out DDLInt))
{
    int searchID;
    if (!int.TryParse(txtSearch.Text.Trim(), out searchID))
        searchID = -1;  // set to an invalid ID


    ItemContext db = new ItemContext();
    var q = (from t0 in db.Item
             join t1 in db.Categories on t0.CategoryID equals t1.CategoryID
             join t2 in db.Divisions on t0.DivisionID equals t2.DivisionID

             where


              t0.DivisionID == DDLInt &&

                 //Contains

            (
             t0.ItemName.Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim()) ||
             t0.Email.Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim()) ||
             t0.Description.Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim()) ||
             t0.Phone.Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim()) ||
             t0.ItemID.Equals(searchID)
             )
             group t0 by new
             {
                 t0.ItemID,
                 t0.ItemName,
                 t0.Description,
                 t0.Phone,
                 t0.Email,
                 t0.DivisionID,
                 t0.CategoryID,
                 t1.CategoryName,
                 t2.DivisionName


             } into i

             select new
             {
                 i.Key.ItemID,
                 i.Key.ItemName,
                 i.Key.Description,
                 i.Key.Email,
                 i.Key.Phone,
                 i.Key.CategoryName,
                 i.Key.DivisionName,
                 i.Key.CategoryID,
                 i.Key.DivisionID

             });

    if (q.Any() == false)
    {
        ResultsLabelId.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ResultsLabelId.Visible = false;
    }

    //bind and return
    lv.DataSource = q.ToList();
    lv.DataBind();
```

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: Do we need _all_ this code to adequately answer your question?

Comment: You tell me if I new the answer I wouldn't of posted it. Was trying to make sure you understood what I was asking. I think the more detail the easier it is to understand. Did you understand it?  Given the question how would you of posted it? Feel free to edit it if you think things aren't needed.

Comment: @jackncoke: You did post too much code, but you kept it to within the function which is what is important. Having entire classes dumped into questions is really what we want to prevent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about replacing that line with:

```
(DDLInt == 5 || t0.DivisionID == DDLInt) &&
```

Comment: I just want to say thank you very much. Not only did you answer my questions cleanly and effectively. You gave me constructive criticism on my question that I appreciated. Comments that just criticize with no tips for improvement or advice to improve should be frowned upon in this site and i commend you for not being one of those people.  I am shocked at how simple that was as well, i was pondering on this for way too long.